# Python script run on command line can't find site packages

Tags: python, importerror

I've written a Python application with Python 2.7 using PyDev for Eclipe, where the script executes perfectly. However, if I try to run it on the command line, I get the following error:

```
importError: No module named openpyxl
```

openpyxl is one of the external libraries I use in my application. I searched for solutions and found multiple threads, some of which on this site. All of them handled modules that were created by the programmer himself and requires appending the src folder to the path. This doesn't work for me. I also tried adding the site package directory to my Python Path, but still the error remains.

Also, the script that is run (main.py) is located in the src directory, like so:

```
/Crawler/
    /src
        __init__.py
        main.py
        /Crawlers
            __init__.py
            Crawler1.py
            Crawler2.py
```

How do I configure my script so it finds all external libraries when executed from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the default python version is actually 2.7. Run `python --version`. If the default is not 2.7, call the script with the 2.7 interpreter;

```
python2.7 <yourscriptname>
```

Or if you are on UNIX or OSX, change the first line of the script to actually call python 2.7;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

*Edit*: If the python version is correct, check that you can import the module from the interactive interpreter. If you get output similar to the one below, `openpyxl` isn't installed correctly.

```
python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 20 2014, 12:09:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final 197956)] on freebsd10
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
>>>
```

Comment: `python --version` returns `python2.7.7`

Comment: @SergioP Try importing it into the interactive interpreter as shown in the edit.

Comment: I do get that output, but I don't understand. How is every module installed correctly except for this one?

Comment: @SergioP Maybe it is a permissions issue. Check that you can open the files in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl` (or whatever the exact name is), and check that a file `__init__.py` exists in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the path variable to find out where python is looking for installed modules

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Your `openpyxl` module has to be in a subfolder of one of them. If this package is not in one of the subfolders there are several solutions. One is as your pointed out to use `PYTHONPATH` and add the folder containing the `openpyxl` on the cmd-line or your can also the `sys` module to add the folder at runtime.

```
import sys
sys,path.append('/path/to/module/')
```

Another method is to install the module into the python-path using the `setup.py` that comes with it, `python setup.py install --user`. Or install it from PyPi with pip, `pip install --user openpyxl`

Comment: Printing the sys.path returns a list of directories, of which one contains the openpyxl module: 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages'

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem because of virtual environment. If you're using venv you have to activate it first in terminal. Go to your project directory, execute `venv\Scripts\activate` and then run your script.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29968655)